# How to assign values from one DF to another, based on equality of values in other column?

Tags: r

Lets say I have big DataFrame and smaller one, which is its subset. Big one has column Y, and smaller has not, both have colmun ID. How, based on equality of values in ID assign values from Y in Big DF to small DF?

Comment: See `?merge` and try searching for `[r] merge` on this site - something like `merge(small,big,by="ID",all.x=TRUE)`. I suggest reading a good intro to R site like http://statmethods.net/ to get these sorts of issues sorted.

Comment: @thelatemail I dont want to merge them, I want that number of rows in resulting DF would be as small DF has. It must be small DF just with new column.

Comment: `merge` can give you what you want. `merge(small,big[c("ID","Y")],by="ID",all.x=TRUE)` if you only want the `Y` column added. It will return multiple values if there are multiple matches in `big`, but you probably want to know that you don't have a nice 1:1 relationship in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If these are your data frames

```
BIG<-data.frame(ID=1:20, Y=runif(20))
SMALL<-data.frame(ID=c(3,7,12))
```

Then you can do the matching using `match()`. For example

```
SMALL$Y<-BIG$Y[match(SMALL$ID, BIG$ID)]
```

Comment: `merge` would be more robust than using `match` in this instance.

Comment: @thelatemail Then post it as an answer so we can up-vote it.

Comment: I won't bother - this is a duplicate question, and I have voted to close rather than answering.